# Removing only an html tag and leaving behind the text inside the tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Just want to remove only the inner tag "span" and don't want to remove the text inside it

```
<blockquote>
      <span>I don’t even bring up technology.</span> 
          I talk about the flow of data.&rdquo;
      <cite>&ndash;Rick Hassman, CIO, Pella</cite>
</blockquote>
```

After parsing it should look like

```
    <blockquote>
            I don’t even bring up technology.
              I talk about the flow of data.&rdquo;
          <cite>&ndash;Rick Hassman, CIO, Pella</cite>
    </blockquote>
```

Please help..

Comment: Yeah I tried with regex... but it was removing all the span tag from the html.... I just wanted to remove the span tag within the blockquote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve it would be to use String.replace() method.

```
String newHtml = html.replaceAll( "<\\/?\\s*span.*?>", "");
```

If you prefer to use Jsoup, then it gets more complicated:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        for (Element e : doc.select("span")) {

            Element parent = e.parent();
            Element newParent = parent.clone();
            newParent.empty();
            for (Node n : parent.childNodes()) {

                if (n instanceof Element && ((Element) n).tag().getName().equals("span")) {
                    newParent.append(((Element) n).html());
                } else {
                    newParent.append(n.outerHtml());
                }

            }
            parent.replaceWith(newParent);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tag is correct and you ask how to do this by Java...

```
String hi = "Hello World!"
String no_o = hi.replaceAll("o", "");
```

...should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringUtils#substringBetween](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), it might save you a lot of effort.

```
String spanText = StringUtils.substringBetween(source, "<span>", "</span>");
String result = source.replaceAll("<span>.+</span>", spanText);
```